# SwiftUI refreshable applies to all scrollViews

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-list

I have a struct containing a List and within that list some other struct Views. Some of those structs contain horizontal scrollViews. When I assign to the List .refreshable that modifier applies to all scrollViews within that list. So all horizontal scrollViews have vertical refreshable properties which is not what I want. Any ideas on how to approach this? Thank you

Comment: You could try to nest the scrollViews in groups or get the scrollViews in separated structs.?!

Comment: @Felix thank you for your reply. They are in different structs

Comment: The secret behind SwiftUI is that a struct with all it's content gets rerendered when a value like a @State object changes. So When you refresh one scrollView of the main struct and the data is based in the main struct it will render all subviews.

Comment: @Felix I understand that but I don't get it why a scrollView in a separate struct gets the main List's modifier properties. Very weird issue and no idea how to solve it. No articles online either..

Comment: @flashspys I ended up using introspect scrollView in my nested views with isDirectionalLockEnabled. But since I asked there was another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74042635/nested-scrollview-in-a-list-refreshable-strange-behaviour-in-ios-16

Answer (score 0):

The refreshable modifier puts a refreshable action in the environment.  If it is cleared out, it should prevent the child scroll views from picking it up.  Here's a pure SwiftUI way of doing it.  This is wrapped up into a convenient modifier but all that is necessary is to clear out the refresh key from the environment. `.environment(\EnvironmentValues.refresh as! WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, RefreshAction?>, nil)`

```
public struct RefreshableBlocker: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let refreshKeyPath = \EnvironmentValues.refresh as? WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, RefreshAction?> {
            content.environment(refreshKeyPath, nil)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
    func blockPullToRefresh() -> some View {
        self.modifier(RefreshableBlocker())
    }
}
```

Just put this somewhere above the child scrollviews in the view hierarchy.  You should be able switch List for ScrollView in the example below.

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 12) {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            ItemCell(data: item).blockPullToRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```